# Fusepy "nothreads" argument explanation

Tags: python-3.x, fuse

I've been fiddling for a bit with the `fuse` package with python3.

When trying to create a FUSE instance, I came across the `nothreads` argument.

Can anyone please elaborate on what this does?

I can guess that setting this flag to `True` the software no longer supports multithreading, but what I would like to know is how it changes the software's behaviour, what would the flow be with and without setting it to `True`?

Thanks